Installing deeplake on virtual environment in a docker container
`Building wheels for collected packages: lz4
Building wheel for lz4 (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for lz4 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [27 lines of output]
/tmp/pip-build-env-j2_1nmhw/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:268: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
warnings.warn(msg)
/tmp/pip-build-env-j2_1nmhw/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools_scm/_integration/setuptools.py:92: UserWarning: version of lz4 already set
warnings.warn(f"version of {dist_name} already set")
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4
copying lz4/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4
copying lz4/version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4/frame
copying lz4/frame/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4/frame
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4/block
copying lz4/block/init.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4/block
running build_ext
building 'lz4._version' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4libs
gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Ilz4libs -I/data/envtest/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c lz4/_version.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/lz4/_version.o -O3 -Wall -Wundef
lz4/_version.c:32:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
32 | #include <Python.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for lz4
Failed to build lz4
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (lz4)`
I get this building wheel error when trying to install the python deeplake library in a virtual environment running in my node-red docker container.
I tried all trivial internet solutions including but not limited to

pip install -r requirements.txt (couldn't find version)
pip install wheel followed by pip install deeplake
all forms of updating pip, pip3, or python3
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
soft linking python in node-red directly to the path


https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

python3.12-dev is already installed. I also don't want to edit my Dockerfile because I have a lot of work done on apps in my current docker containers

Where is Python.h in the container?
